# Error on Datagridview.rows.add from MSAccess Database using Backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
    SampleOnly(dgvProductList)
End Sub

Sub SampleOnly(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    Try
        If dgv.InvokeRequired Then
            dgv.Invoke(Sub() dgv.Rows.Clear())
        Else
            dgv.Rows.Clear()
        End If

        Dim i As Integer
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Open()
        End If
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select ProductID,Barcode,AKA,ProductName,Principal,CPrice,PPrice,Quantity from Product", cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            i += 1
            If dgv.InvokeRequired Then
                dgv.Invoke(Sub()
                               dgvProductList.Rows.Add(i, dr.Item("ProductID").ToString, dr.Item("Barcode").ToString, dr.Item("AKA").ToString, dr.Item("ProductName").ToString, dr.Item("Principal").ToString, dr.Item("CPrice").ToString, dr.Item("PPrice").ToString, dr.Item("Quantity").ToString)
                               dgvProductList.ClearSelection()
                           End Sub)
            Else
                dgvProductList.Rows.Add(i, dr.Item("ProductID").ToString, dr.Item("Barcode").ToString, dr.Item("AKA").ToString, dr.Item("ProductName").ToString, dr.Item("Principal").ToString, dr.Item("CPrice").ToString, dr.Item("PPrice").ToString, dr.Item("Quantity").ToString)
                dgvProductList.ClearSelection()
            End If
            Thread.Sleep(500)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
    MsgBox("Done!")
End Sub
```

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IRowset'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{0C733A7C-2A1C-11CE-ADE5-00AA0044773D}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Can someone atleast give me an idea why Im getting this message on `dgvProductList.Rows.Add(i, dr.Item("ProductID").ToString, dr.Item("Barcode").ToString, dr.Item("AKA").ToString, dr.Item("ProductName").ToString, dr.Item("Principal").ToString, dr.Item("CPrice").ToString, dr.Item("PPrice").ToString, dr.Item("Quantity").ToString)`
Thanks

Comment: Don't use a BackgroundWorker to handle UI elements. You can generate, e.g., a DataTable (could be any other type of *collection* that can be set as the source of data of a Control) and pass this object to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event's `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`.  The set the object you created to the DataSource property of your DataGridView. Don't Invoke from the DoWork event of a BackgroundWorker, ever. You have the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events for that (these event are raised in the UI Thread).

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for giving me an idea on backgroudworker, Ill work on your recommendation. Thanks again

Comment: The whole point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to do background work and anything to do with the UI is the exact opposite of background work. To see some explanation and examples of what Jimi described, see [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889).

Comment: Connections, commands and datareaders need to be disposed. Declare them in the method where they are used in a Using block. Using...End Using will closed and dispose these objects even if there is an error.